# Reverse Curve Guide Direction

Tags: particles, bezier-curves, force-fields

When I create a curve and add 'Curve Guide' Force field, at one end there is a dotted circle and the other end a solid circle. As far as I have understood, the solid circle is for particle start and the dotted one is the end points. But I whenever I create the curve guide force field it automatically sets a start and end point. is there a way to reverse it ? Like interchange the solid and dotted circles keeping the curve as it is ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to reverse the curve's normals direction: select it, go in *Edit* mode, then right click > *Switch Direction*.

To display the normals, go into the *Viewport Overlays* and enable *Normals*:

[image]

Comment: If possible may you also give the python code for that ?

Comment: I don't know anything about python, I guess you can get the code with the Info window?

Comment: Oh yes. I have got it. Thank you for the help.